# Angular can get data from Web Api

Tags: angularjs

Hi  i try to get data from my web API with Angular but i get 404 not found the code is

**Html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Simple Web  Application</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Ename}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Angular code:**

```
var url = "http://localhost:65125/api/Empyloee";
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

var MainController = function ($scope, $http) {
    var onSucess = function (response) { $scope.employees = response.data};
    var onFailure = function (reason) { $scope.error = reason };
    var getAllEmployees = function () {
        $http.get(url)
            .then(onSucess ,onFailure)
    };

    getAllEmployees();
};

myApp.controller("MainController", MainController);
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Please correct you question - paste code here and be more specific.

Comment: Any error in console? Where you able to data from API, please check network console..

Comment: console show 404 not found work with postman without any problem

Comment: Are you sure your url is correct? You seem to have a typo in `"http://localhost:65125/api/Empyloee"` which I assume was meant to be `Employee`. So unless you have the same typo in your API endpoint, you'll get this 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with that endpoint in your API side. Re-test you API endpoint if it's working correctly. You can check response using POSTMAN before integrate with your angular solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer i verify my end point , and use POSTMAN and i get the data without any problem.

Comment: sometimes are missing "/" in url, or some mistake in the url. Try with another foo endpoint and integrate step by step your logic inside there if it is not too long.